# httpClient inside submit called procedure [GeneXus 18u3]

Tags: http, asynchronous, genexus

I'm calling a procedure via submit like `doWork.submit('')`.

Inside that, I call a procedure `makeRequestAndGetResult(string)` in a module that calls and returns a string from httpClient. I am sure this procedure does the job and returns the httpClient correctly when I call `doWork.Call()`.

```
log('> ' + &body) // this is logged
&response = myModule.makeRequestAndGetResult(&body)
log('> ' + &response_tx) // this is not logged
```

And I am also sure the `&body` I'm passing has value. The thing is that when I call `makeRequestAndGetResult`, it seems that the code stops there, because the second log() does not logs the string to my log table as it should. The `log()` function commits. So, I don't even know if `&response` is null or not.

What makes it stop working via submit? And how can I fix it?

I expect to log my second `log()`.
I don't want to call `doWork()` without submit, since it is inside a for loop and I need to improve the performance.

Comment: Your variable is &response, but you log &response_tx... Is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

## It was a httpClient poolsize error

Since I was calling it too many times at once. To solve this, instead of doing

```
for each ...
    doWork.submit()
endfor
```

I started to iterate inside doWork.